# brew upgrade removes dock icon in BigSur

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur, homebrew-cask

whenever I run `brew update && brew upgrade && brew upgrade --cask` it updates my apps and removes the app icons from the macOS dock as well. after every upgrade I have to add the app icon back to the dock. quite annoying. this is on BigSur. this did not happen when I was on Catalina. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe after the updade, you can : right click at the top left (in the Apple logo) > force to quit > click on Finder > restart

Comment: I've tried this but still the same. the dock icon is removed and I have to add it again.

Answer (score 2):

[Issue #102721 was created for this on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/102721). It has not been fixed yet. User vitorgalvao described the behavior as:

> Interesting. It seems that after an app has been uninstalled for a few
> seconds, it will be auto-removed from the Dock. That’s good smart
> behaviour, which happens to clash with our way of doing things.
>
> I agree this is something that should be fixed, but I also have no
> immediate solution. Whatever we do is bound to require changes to the
> upgrade and/or reinstall behaviours, so I wouldn’t expect this to be
> fixed soon.

He also posted this workaround until the issue has been fixed:

```
defaults export com.apple.dock "/path/to/temporary/file"

# Do the upgrade/reinstall as usual

defaults import com.apple.dock "/path/to/temporary/file"
killall Dock
```

> It makes the Dock “flash” by being killed and reopened, but at least
> it the result at the end is the desired one.